# Automatically open a menu when we hover the icon (ng-office-ui-fabric)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ms-office, office-js, office-ui-fabric

I want to use office-ui-fabric with angularjs, so I am trying to use [ng-office-ui-fabric](http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/uifCommandBar/).

To make a command bar, I have found [this example](http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/uifCommandBar/). However, there is a problem about a dropdown button (eg, `14th`). When I click on `14th` or its icon, the menu is not opened. Is it normal?

Additionally, what I want to achieve is actually: when we hover its icon, the menu is open.

Does anyone know how to do this?

PS: a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pegaremuce/1/edit?html,output) where clicking on `14th` does not open the menu (Chrome, mac).

Comment: You can use ng-mouseover event to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, on hover set a flag to true on leaving set that flag to false.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-mouseleave="val = false" ng-mouseover="val = true" ng-init="val=false">Mouse over me!</div>
<span ng-show="val"> This is being displayed on mouseover</span>


</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngOfficeUiFabric/0.15.3/ngOfficeUiFabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="YourApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="YourController">

          
      
  <a href ng-click="toggleMenu()">14</a>
      <uif-contextual-menu uif-is-open="dynamic.opened">
        <uif-contextual-menu-item uif-text="'New'"></uif-contextual-menu-item>
        <uif-contextual-menu-item uif-text="'Edit'"></uif-contextual-menu-item>
        <uif-contextual-menu-item uif-text="'Delete'"></uif-contextual-menu-item>
        <uif-contextual-menu-item uif-type="divider"></uif-contextual-menu-item>
        <uif-contextual-menu-item uif-text="'Settings'"></uif-contextual-menu-item>
      </uif-contextual-menu>

  </div>
 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    angular.module('YourApp', ['officeuifabric.core', 'officeuifabric.components'])
    .controller('YourController', function ($scope) {      $scope.isOpen = true;
      $scope.dynamic = {};
      $scope.dynamic.opened = false;
      $scope.toggleMenu = function () {
        $scope.dynamic.opened = !$scope.dynamic.opened;
      };});
  </script> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you... but how could I apply this to `uif-contextual-menu`? I even cannot display it by clicking... [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pegaremuce/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Can you create a plunker or show some code snippet on how u are trying to achieve this?

Comment: What should happen when u click on 14th?

Comment: You have not written any js coded in you jsBin. Update it with your js code

Comment: But what should I write in eg., `openMenu()`?

Comment: Cool, as a record, here is [a version](https://jsbin.com/canoxejeru/1/edit?html,output) that works with hover...

Answer (score 2):

you can use `on-mouseover='over()'` for hover effects, also write the over() method.
About the 14th not opening - not sure, but it works for me (google chrome win10)

Comment: How could I write `over()` which opens the menu? Also, did you write somewhere `openMenu()` for `ng-click="openMenu()"`?

Comment: are you using angulerjs or angular 2?

Comment: i am using angular 1.5.7

Comment: ok, so basiclly you'd want to set a variable as 'false' (name it yourVariablehere for example) and use ngShow directive for this task. Make a div with ngShow = yourVariablehere (which will be hidden since the variable's value is set to false), next thing, add a  ng-mouseover directive to some element, the one which you want to "hover", and set the value of the directive to  ng-mouseover= yourVariablehere  = !yourVariablehere , this should do the trick

Comment: wrote a small piece of code for you, can be found here
https://pastebin.com/gS2U23mR

Comment: I just made a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pegaremuce/1/edit?html,output), does clicking on `14th` opens the menu on your side?